# shift/reduce conflict - identifier

Tags: grammar, shift-reduce-conflict

I have a shift-reduce conflict in this part of code....

```
<Designator> ::= <Qualident>
          | <Qualident> <auxDesignator>
<auxDesignator> ::= '.' Identifier
             | '[' <ExpressionList> ']'
             | '^'
             | <auxDesignator> '.' Identifier
             | <auxDesignator> '[' <ExpressionList> ']'
             | <auxDesignator> '^'

<Qualident> ::= Identifier 
         | Identifier <auxIdentifier>
<auxIdentifier> ::= '.' Identifier
             | <auxIdentifier> '.' Identifier
```

I have a shift-reduce conflit when I wrote this line os code

```
<auxDesignator> ::= '.' Identifier
```

but this line is necessary to respect the grammar, anyone can help me please?

Comment: Could you explain your intention? Since both   `<auxIdentifier>` and  `<auxIdentifier>` match `'.' Identifier`, it is impossible for the parser to know which one to pick. I don't know either; if you know, it would be helpful if you could explain. (The context is the sentence `id.x`: what is `.x` and why?)

Comment: this are two rules of one grammar (modula-2). A designator is one qualident followed by zero or more of `( '.' Identifier |  '[' <ExpressionList> ']' | '^')`. A qualident is a Identifier followed by zero or more of ( '.' Identifier). a identifier is one terminal. I'm trying to make this grammar using goldparser.

Comment: Please edit your question with the additional information. And you did not answer my query: in `id.x`, what is `x` and why? (Is it part of a designator or a qualident?)